# How to send not declared selector without performSelector:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, thrift, nsproxy

**Background:**
I have an object (let's call it `BackendClient`) that represents connection with server. Its methods are generated to single `@protocol` and they are all synchronous, so I want to create proxy object that will call them in background. The main problem is return value, which I obviously can't return from async method, so I need to pass a callback. The "easy" way will be copy all `BackendClient`'s methods and add callback argument. But that's not very dynamic way of solving that problem, while ObjectiveC nature is dynamic. That's where `performSelector:` appears. It solves problem entirely, but it almost kills proxy object transparency.

**Problem:**
I want to be able to send not declared selector to proxy (subclass of `NSProxy`) object as if it was already declared.
For example, I have method:

```
-(AuthResponse)authByRequest:(AuthRequest*)request
```

in `BackendClient` protocol. And I want proxy call look like this:

```
[proxyClient authByRequest:myRequest withCallback:myCallback];
```

But this wouldn't compile because

> No visible @interface for 'BackendClientProxy' declares the selector 'authByRequest:withCallBack:'

OK. Let's calm down compiler a bit:

```
[(id)proxyClient authByRequest:myRequest withCallback:myCallback];
```

Awww. Another error:

> No known instance method for selector 'authByRequest:withCallBack:'

The only thing that comes to my mind and this point is somehow construct new `@protocol` with needed methods at runtime, but I have no idea how to do that.

**Conclusion:** I need to suppress this compilation error. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you are deep down the mats-programming / dynamic runtime rabbit hole.   While ObjC does have roots in SmallTalk and *can* be bent to that will, it really isn't a natural fit at all.  In general, heavy use of `performSelector:` or proxies is considered a *code smell* in that it is often difficult to maintain over time.

Comment: So, what will be the right way ask achieve async wrap around client methods? Just copy-past all methods and add callback argument to them?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it, you have a synchronous, non-threaded, API that you want to be asynchronous for purposes of not blocking, say, the main event loop, etc...

I would add a serial queue to BackgroundClient:

```
@property(strong) dispatch_queue_t serialQueue;

 ... somewhere in your -init ...
 _serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create(..., serial constant);
```

Then:

```
 - (void)dispatchOperation:(dispatch_block_t)anOperation
 {
      dispatch_async(_serialQueue, anOperation);
 }
```

That can be used like:

```
 [myClient dispatchOperation:^{
       [myClient doSynchronousA];
       id result = [myClient doSynchronousB];
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [someone updateUIWithResult:result];
       }
 }];
```

That is the easiest way to move the BackgroundClient to an asynchronous model without rewriting it or heavily refactoring it.

If you want to harden the API, then create a class wrapper for BackendClient that holds an instance of the client and the serial queue.   Make it such that said class instantiates the client and the rest of your code *only* retrieves instances from that wrapper.  That'll allow you to still have the same `dispatchOperation:` model, but not require mirroring all the methods.

---

typedef void(^ AsyncBackendBlock(BackendClient* bc);
     @interface AsyncBackend
     +(instancetype)asyncBackendWithBackend:(BackendClient*)bc;

```
 @property .... serialQueue;

 - (void) dispatchAsync:(AsyncBackendBlock) backBlock;
 @end
```

.m:

```
 @interface AsyncBackend()
 @property... BackendClient *client;
 @end

 @implementation AsyncBackend

 - (void) dispatchAsync:(AsyncBackendBlock) backBlock
 {
     dispatch_async(_serialQueue, ^{
         backBlock(_client);
     });
 }
 @end
```

Caller:

```
 AsyncBackend *b = [AsyncBackend asyncBackendWithBackend:[BackendClient new]];
 [b dispatchAsync:^(BackendClient *bc) {
    [bc doSomething];
    id result = [bc retrieveSomething];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [uiThingy updateWithResult:result];
    }
 }];
 ....
```

Comment: I don't get last 2 sentences. OK, let's assume I have such wrapper, let's call it `BackendClientWrapper`, there is `client` property in it. Now, how do I call backend methods?

Comment: Now I get it. You can keep this queue wherever you want. Well, thanks for option! Sad I can't do it transparently.

Answer (score 0):

To look up a selector at runtime, you can use `NSSelectorFromString()`, but in this case you should just go ahead and import whatever  header you need to get the declaration of `-authByRequest:`

Comment: Creating selector from string in this case would be the same as `performSelector:`. And yes, I can get `authByRequest:` selector, but I need `authByRequest:withCallback:`.